# Group by year in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to group by year but  was not able to do.I can get the column count but not year wise. this is what i tried.

```
 select  t_contract ,
    sum(CASE t_contract when '18' then 1 else 0 end) as XL, 
    sum(CASE t_contract when '01' then 1 else 0 end) as VC,
    sum(CASE t_contract when '75'    then 1 else 0 end) as AN,
    sum(CASE t_contract when '48'    then 1 else 0 end) as CS

    from icps.dbo.tickets
    WHERE 
     t_date_time_issued >= DATEADD(year, -6, GETDATE())
        GROUP BY contract
```

.. but i want to add  year .. where i have `t_date_time _issued` column.
My another query is I have a column called `t_zone_name` and I want to sum all the rows where `t_zone_anme like '%ICeland%'` an i tried this:

```
 sum(CASE t_zone_name like '%ICeland%'    then 1 else 0 end) as ICELAND
```

but I get an  error on statement like... thanks in advance.

LIKE

```
YEAR XL  VC  AN  CS total 
2010 50  50  50  50  200
2011  5   5   5  5   20
```

Comment: Is t_zone_name a nullable field?

Comment: Which SQL engine? Oracle, mysql??

Comment: sql server and t_zone_name_name is nullable

Comment: sum(CASE ( t_zone_name is not null and t_zone_name like '%ICeland%')    then 1 else 0 end) as ICELAND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT t_contract, YEAR(t_date_time_issued) As Yr, SUM(CASE WHEN t_zone_name like '%ICeland%'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ICELAND

SUM(CASE t_contract when '18' then 1 else 0 end) as XL, 
SUM(CASE t_contract when '01' then 1 else 0 end) as VC,
SUM(CASE t_contract when '75'    then 1 else 0 end) as AN,
SUM(CASE t_contract when '48'    then 1 else 0 end) as CS

FROM icps.dbo.tickets
WHERE YEAR(t_date_time_issued) >= (YEAR(GetDate()) - 6)
GROUP BY t_contract, YEAR(t_date_time_issued)
```

You might need change the order of `t_contract` and  `YEAR(t_date_time_issued)` depending on which grouping you want to apply first.

As suggested by @ray I have replaced `DATEPART(yyyy, t_date_time_issued) >= DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(year, -6, GETDATE()))` with `year(t_date_time_issued) >= (year(GetDate()) - 6)`

Comment: 't_date_time_issued' is not a recognized datepart option.
i get this error

Comment: what is the datatype  of 't_date_time_issued'  column?

Comment: its datetime  i dont know why and I am using Sql Server Mangament Studio

Comment: just use " where year(t_date_time_issued) >= (year(GetDate()) - 6) "

Comment: Oh, there was error in syntax, I have edited it, check the query now

Comment: @ray has suggested a better function to use. You can try that too.

Comment: Dipendu ,thanks for your help.....  I tried your query its working expect with added column for ICeland but I am still not getting the yearwise data.

Comment: Ok let me understand your requirement a little better way, do you want show a `Year` column at the output resultset and GROUP the data you are getting currently by `Year` as well in addition to t_contract?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48251/discussion-between-dipendu-paul-and-preethi)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by year, in sql server, you might

```
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(year,t_date_time_issued, GETDATE())
```

In other DB engine, usually has method to get year part, or use substring to get year part from a time string.

Comment: is not  " Group By Year(t_date_time _issued) " enough?